# return the value uuid in the nodes created in Neo4j ogm

Tags: neo4j, graphaware, neo4j-php-ogm

I'm working Neo4j from PHP. To generate the uuid field in the nodes I am using: [neo4j-uuid](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid/blob/master/README.md).
I also use: [graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm](https://packagist.org/packages/graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm), when I create a node, I do not return the value assigned to the UUID field, I have to make a new query to get that value, I need to hydrate the UUID value automatically when the object is created, just like the ID is hydrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the GraphAware Neo4j UUID [Github Repo](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid#using-graphaware-uuid):

> If you create a node and return it immediately, its contents will not
>   reflect changes performed by transaction event handlers such as this
>   one -- thus the UUID will not be available. A separate call must be
>   made to get the UUID.

That is: this is the expected behavior. Currently you should make a new query to get the node with the generated UUID property.

Comment: Through php metadata, is there any way to specify that the uuid field be treated as an ID?

Comment: Hi @JaimeRoman.Thanks for accepting my answer. Unfortunately I'm not a PHP developer. So I cannot help you with this subject. Sorry. Maybe you should make a new question about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @bruno-peres

Answer (score 0):

As it says @bruno-peres the value of the uuid is not automatically hydrated, so I invoke the refresh method of the EntityManager

```
$this->em->persist($entity);
$this->em->flush();
$this->em->refresh($entity);
var_dump($p->getUuid())
```